# PACKAGE BODY MISTAKE

Tags: plsql, package

```
-- PACKAGE SPECIFICATION OR HEADER
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE pkg_Answer2 IS
  FUNCTION grade_std(marks NUMBER) RETURN VARCHAR2;
END pkg_Answer2;
/

--PACKAGE BODY
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY pkg_Answer2 IS 
  --FUNCTION IMPLEMENTATION
  FUNCTION grade_std(marks NUMBER) RETURN VARCHAR2 IS
    BEGIN 
      IF marks>90 THEN 
        RETURN 'A';
      ELSIF marks<=90 AND marks>80 THEN 
        RETURN 'B';
      ELSIF marks<=80 AND marks>70 THEN  
        RETURN 'C';
      ELSIF marks<=70 AND marks>60 THEN 
        RETURN 'D';
      ELSIF marks<=60
        RETURN 'F';
      ELSE
        RETURN 'I';
      END IF;
    END grade_std;
   
END pkg_Answer2;
```

PACKAGE BODY IS SHOWING ERROR :

Errors: PACKAGE BODY PKG_ANSWER2
Line/Col: 14/9 PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "RETURN" when expecting one of the following:

- & - + / at mod remainder rem then <an exponent (**)> and or
  || multiset

WHAT DOES IT MEAN BU ENCOUNTER SYMBOL RETURN THUS I AM UNABLE TO CREATE PACKAGE BODY

Comment: You should **avoid** writing your whole question in **ALL CAPS** - this is generally considered **SHOUTING** at your audience, it's rude and offensive, and dramatically lowers your chances of folks taking their time to read your question and provide an answer. Don't do it - just don't .

Comment: Ok I will consider it from next time sir 

Answer (score 1):

This is basic debugging, you should not have to ask this on stack overflow. All the information is right in your question.
To find out what is going on:

- Open the created package in a tool like sql developer. That tool highlights the line where error occurs (Line 14, as shown in the error)
- Check what is happening around line 14...

```
13      ELSIF marks<=60
14        RETURN 'F';
15      ELSE
```

- the error states "Encountered the symbol "RETURN" when ". This means it cannot compile because a previous expression does not have correct syntax and the word "RETURN" doesn't make any sense there... so check the line before. That is line 13. It does not have the `THEN` keyword. There is your error.

Comment: Ok I will consider it from next point sir 